# I get the error: "Reboot and Select proper Boot device"

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios, gpt

After I got a new and bigger SSD, I wanted to install Windows 10 on it. For some reason BIOS did not list my bootable USB device, with the Windows 10 installation. So I connected it thorugh SATA instead, and now it would let me install Windows 10. Problem is, everytime I disconnect the HDD where the Windows 10 installation is located, I get the error: "Reboot and Select proper Boot device" during boot. When I connect the HDD, it seems to boot from the installation HDD, and let me choose to open into Windows 10 (on the SSD). I can then use Windows 10 normally.

**Som other info:**

When the installation HDD is disconnected and I go into BIOS, the SSD is the only thing listed under boot devices. If I choose the SSD manually from BIOS, I get the same error message.

At first under the Windows 10 installation, I coulnd't install on the SSD because of it being a GPT-partition. I used Diskpart and then installed Windows 10.

I have tried to set the SSD as "active" with Diskpart.

**BIOS Mode**

MSInfo32 shows: Legacy

Title shown in BIOS menu: UEFI BIOS Utility - EZ Mode

[BIOS when old and new SSD is connected. The old SSD (with working Windows 10) has the UEFI label.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VKkU.jpg)

Comment: BIOS (Legacy) or UEFI? Different procedures...

Comment: Probably your partition containing the installer on the hdd is now marked as the "System" partition. Could you check that in disk management? Meaning you don't have a rescue system partition installed on the ssd.

Comment: I think you are right. I don't have a rescue system partition installed on the SSD. Why is that? Wouldn't it normally be created when installing Windows 10?

Comment: This is really messed up. You could just install BCD on you windows partition. But I would highly recommend to try again with your installation hdd connected via usb. Make sure you find the boot option labled UEFI. Your usb device should show up twice, take the UEFI one.

Comment: Why is that? That's what the window setup used to do if it finds an internal hard drive with an existing BCD boot loader. Maybe you like it that way. Saves space on the ssd :)

Comment: I would also like to install from USB, but the problem is that it's not listed in BIOS. I tried the USB on my laptop, where it worked perfectly. Is it because of a specific setting in BIOS, that won't let me see the USB?

Comment: Running the installer from usb will create a rescue partition on the ssd and it will be self contained.

Comment: USB boot could be disabled somewhere yes. I'm sure you will find it somewhere.

Comment: Say something is wrong with the USB device, would you recommend rebuilding the Boot Configuration Data with the bootrec command?

Comment: Be aware that all that automatic repair stuff from the rescue will not be available if you take the hdd out. You can install BCD either from commandline or with graphical tools like easybcd or more advanced visual bcd. If you are curious, go ahead.

Comment: Actually I remembered that wrong, repair images reside in rescue folder on your C: in this case. So saves no space and might maybe work. Could need extra entry in BCD, don't know.

Comment: By the way. How big is your partition on the hdd for the windows installer. Bioses are often limited and won't recognize if too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a USB drive that worked. I'm not sure what went wrong, when trying to connect. Now I got a fully functional Windows 10.